# $n$th term of a Maclaurin series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am having some confusion about the $n$th term of a Maclaurin series.

For instance, $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + ... + \frac{x^n}{n!}+...$

The general term is $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ but in reality that is the series’ $(n+1)$st term.

We do similar for the series for sin and cos, where we essentially start with the $n=0$ term when writing a general expression for the term in the series.

---

However there is some inconsistency because I have done a recent exercise which asks:

> Find the $n$th non-zero term in the Maclaurin series of $y= \sin x \sinh x$.

The series itself goes $x^2 - \frac{x^6}{90} + \frac{x^{10}}{113400}+...$

However, the $n$th term is given as $2 \times (-4)^{n-1} \frac{x^{4n-2}}{(4n-2)!}$ which works if $x^2$ is regarded as the 1st term rather than the 0th term.

So now I am confused - is there a convention I am missing?

Comment: A common  convention for power series is that the $n$th term is the one that contains $x^n$. The constant term is the $0$th.  That convention might not be in effect in what you are reading. Not something to worry about - just adjust.

Comment: It's not really a math question as much as english/syntax. I might just refer to the $x^{4n-2}$ term or whatever to avoid confusion. Otherwise I'd ask for clarification. If you can't, then just pick the most reasonable interpretation and state your interpretation.

Comment: There is a change that at some point you will learn about derivatives and anti derivatives to manipulate given powerseries into "new" powerseries. Also in that case you may have to "adjust" your starting $n$ value. No big deal...

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The problem is formulated correctly. Note, it is asking for the $n$-th *non-zero* term. This is the summand with index $4n-2$.